# Python | Make the percentage of a list

Tags: python

So I have this code :

```
from random import *
from math import *
n=int(input("n="))
sommes = [0]*12
for i in range(1,n+1):
 r=randint(1,6)+randint(1,6)
 if r==1:
  sommes[0] += 1
 if r==2:
  sommes[1] += 1
 if r==3:
  sommes[2] += 1
 if r==4:
  sommes[3] += 1
 if r==5:
  sommes[4] += 1
 if r==6:
  sommes[5] += 1
 if r==7:
  sommes[6] += 1
 if r==8:
  sommes[7] += 1
 if r==9:
  sommes[8] += 1
 if r==10:
  sommes[9] += 1
 if r==11:
  sommes[10] += 1
 if r==12:
  sommes[11] += 1
print(sommes)
```

And I want to know if I can reduce/optimise that part :

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
 r=randint(1,6)+randint(1,6)
 if r==1:
  sommes[0] += 1
 if r==2:
  sommes[1] += 1
 if r==3:
  sommes[2] += 1
 if r==4:
  sommes[3] += 1
 if r==5:
  sommes[4] += 1
 if r==6:
  sommes[5] += 1
 if r==7:
  sommes[6] += 1
 if r==8:
  sommes[7] += 1
 if r==9:
  sommes[8] += 1
 if r==10:
  sommes[9] += 1
 if r==11:
  sommes[10] += 1
 if r==12:
  sommes[11] += 1
```

And how can I make sure to give the result as a percentage for each number in the list (1 to 12) like
that [2, 23, 4, 48, 21] to that [2%, 12%, 4%, 43%, 23%]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an integer, `r`. You can just use `r-1` as the index to `sommes`

```
from random import randint
n=int(input("n="))
sommes = [0]*12
for i in range(1,n+1):
   r=randint(1,6)+randint(1,6)
   sommes[r-1] += 1
```

For the percentages part you can just divide everything by n and multiply by 100:

```
y = [int(x/n*100) for x in sommes]
```

(although if you use integers as in your example, it won't add up to 100). 
or if you want a list of strings with percentages you can use this format. This does have the advantage that you can control how many decimal places the strings have. `.0f` is 0, but you could change the 0 for the number of decimal places you want.

```
y = [f"{x/n*100:.0f}%" for x in sommes]
```

I've also optimised the inputs as it's not efficient to use `from random import *` if you're only using `randint`

Comment: So does this work ?                                                                                                  
from random import *
from math import *
n=int(input("n="))
sommes = [0]*12
for i in range(1,n+1):
   r=randint(1,6)+randint(1,6)
   sommes[r-1] += 1
y = [int(x/n*100) for x in sommes]
print(sommes)

Comment: Yes but I can't see the difference between the one with the line y = [int(x/n*100) for x in sommes] and the one without it

Comment: It's converting `sommes` to rounded percentages, so if I run the program with `n=5000`, I've just got `sommes` of `[0, 121, 271, 416, 536, 675, 862, 712, 580, 410, 285, 132]`, and `y` is the same thing converted to a percentage distribution, `[0, 2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 14, 11, 8, 5, 2]`. Is that not what you were after?

Comment: If instead you wanted y as a list of strings with percentage signs, per your example, you could use `y = [f"{int(x/n*100)}%" for x in sommes]` instead. That would return something like `['0%', '2%', '4%', '9%', '12%', '14%', '15%', '13%', '12%', '7%', '5%', '2%']`

Answer (score 1):

Notice how you're always using an index of `r-1` to access and update your `sommes` array.

With that in mind, your code could be simplified to:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
 r=randint(1,6)+randint(1,6)
 sommes[r-1] += 1
```

As for calculating percentages, you could print the result as:

`print("%.0f%%" % (100 * sommes[i] / n))`

This will limit your number to not showing decimals (`%.0f`) and show your number of occurrences for each number divided by the total number of dices.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging `Counter` from the standard library:

```
from random import *
from math import *
from collections import Counter
#n=int(input("n="))
n=10  # for example
r = range(n)
rands = (randint(1,6)+randint(1,6) for _ in r)
sommes = Counter(rands)
print(sommes)
perc = [int(sommes[i]/n*100) for i in r]
print(perc)
```

produces

```
Counter({3: 2, 6: 2, 12: 2, 7: 1, 11: 1, 9: 1, 8: 1})
[0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 20, 10, 10, 10]
```